# Closed form for $\prod_{k = 1}^{n} \sqrt{1 - \cos(a_k - b_k)}$?

Tags: closed-form, fourier-transform

When calculating $\prod_{k = 1}^{n} | e^{-i b_k \xi_k} - e^{-i a_k \xi_k} |$, I found out that (I'll omit the index for simplicity)
$$
| e^{-i b} - e^{-i a} |
= \sqrt{\left(-\cos(a) + \cos(b)\right)^2 + \left(\sin(a)- \sin(b)\right)^2}
= \sqrt{2} \sqrt{1 - \cos(a - b)}
= 2 \left| \sin\left(\frac{a - b}{2}\right) \right|.
$$
for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.
I wondered if the is a closed form (no product) of
$$
\prod_{k = 1}^{n} \sqrt{1 - \cos(a_k - b_k)},
$$
where $b_k > a_k$ are real numbers.

Comment: @RonGordon We do have formulas like [those](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sines_and_cosines_of_sums_of_infinitely_many_angles) without knowing the values of of the $\theta_k$. Another example is [Viete`s infinite product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Viète's_infinite_product).

Comment: For Viete's product, $a_k = \theta/2^k$ and $b_k=0$, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordance with the OP,
$$P\left(\vec a,\vec b\right)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\sqrt{1-\cos(a_k-b_k)} = 2^{\large^n\!/\!_2}
\left|\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\sin\dfrac{a_k-b_k}2\right|.$$

To avoid infinity productions, the logarithmic function can be used:
$$P\left(\vec a,\vec b\right)=
\begin{cases}
0,\quad\text{if}\quad \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n\left(\dfrac{a_k-b_k}{2\pi}\in\mathbb N\right),\\
2^{\large^n\!/\!_2}\exp\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\ln\left|\sin\dfrac{a_k-b_k}2\right|\right),\quad\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: But there's no closed form for the finite product of the $\sin$ of $\frac{a_k - b_k}{2}$?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik If to denote $C_k=\sin\dfrac{a_k-b_k}2,$ it becames clearly that the  given task is equivalent to the task about the closed form for the production of the arbitrary set of the bounded numbers . Proposed solution corresponds with this task.